# How to Flip a div and show different sized content on front and back?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a `div` "flipcard" element that contains different sized content on the front and back.

The HTML:

```
 <div class="flipcard">
    <div class="face front">Front</div>
    <div class="face back">Back ... put some long text here ... </div>
 </div>
```

The Javascript just adds and removes a "flipped" class:

```
$('.flipcard').click(function(e) {
    var $card = $(this);
    if ($card.hasClass("flipped")) $card.removeClass('flipped');
    else $card.addClass('flipped');
});
```

All the magic happens in the CSS:

```
.flipcard {
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 80%;
    /* I don't want to set the height because 
       we don't know the size of the content */
    border: solid 1em white;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    font-family: Georgia;
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flipcard:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
}
.flipcard.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.flipcard .face {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .front {
    background: #220000;
    color: white;
}
.flipcard .back {
    background: #66eeff;
    color: black;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luken/qdBEV/
As you can see, the content from the front is interfering with the back, and they both stretch the flipcard to the combined height. I'd like the front to show with the proper height of its content and the back to show with the proper height of its content. I've tried making the faces `position: absolute` and making them go from `display: none` to `display: block` on each flip... but nothing works quite right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Add proper `display:none;` and `display:block;`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qdBEV/3/

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #bbb;
}
.flipcard {
    perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective: 800;
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 80%;
    border: solid 1em white;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    font-family: Georgia;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flipcard:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
}
.flipcard.flipped {
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.flipcard .face {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .front {
    background: #220000;
    color: white;
    display: block; /* added to fix the problem */
}
.flipcard.flipped .front {
    display:none; /* added to fix the problem */
}
.flipcard .back {
    background: #66eeff;
    color: black;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    display:none; /* added to fix the problem */
}
.flipcard.flipped .back {
    display:block; /* added to fix the problem */
}
```

Comment: This seems to cause a problem where the 'back' side is no longer clickable. (Tested your jsfiddle in Chrome 31.0.1650.63)

Comment: @Luke Works fine here, same Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m

Answer (score 3):

I had to implement this problem at work and maybe this post will help others, so here is what I came up with (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ee8nvda/)). First off, the requirements in my case were a bit tighter than a flipping `div` with different height faces. Additionally:

1. There is content below the flip card that has to shift up and down smoothly (e.g. another CSS transiton) while the card flips in order to accommodate for the different heights of the faces.
2. The content **on** the faces as well as what is above and below the flip card has to adhere to the responsive design of the page, in other words the card cannot have any fixed CSS dimensions nor absolute positioning.
3. Support for all major browsers, but only latest versions.

HTML is the same as in the question - one "card" with two "faces":

```
<div class="flipcard">
  <div class="flipcard-front">
    <h1>Front</h1>
    <p>some shorter content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flipcard-back">
    <h1>Back</h1>
    <p>some long content</p>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (looks daunting, but actually just a couple of line of LESS):

```
.flipcard {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 0px;
  /* Flip card styles: WebKit, FF, Opera */
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
     -moz-perspective: 800px;
       -o-perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s, -webkit-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s, -moz-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
       -o-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s, -o-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
  /* only height adjustment for IE here */
      -ms-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s;
}
 /* The class that flips the card: WebKit, FF, Opera */
.flipcard.card-flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard .flipcard-front,
.flipcard .flipcard-back {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* backface: all browsers */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Flip card styles: IE 10,11 */
  -ms-perspective: 800px;
  -ms-transform-style: flat;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
}
.flipcard .flipcard-front {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipcard .flipcard-back {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
      -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
       -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /*  webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54371,
      You need this fix if you have any input tags on your back face */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
}
 /* The 2 classes that flip the faces instead of the card: IE 10,11 */
.flipcard .flipcard-front.ms-front-flipped {
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard .flipcard-back.ms-back-flipped {
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

*Notes*: Unfortunately the latest versions of IE still handle CSS rotations differently than all the others in that it expects each **face** to be flipped individually instead of flipping the card that contains them. Although webKit browsers, FF and Opera seem to "understand" this, I wanted maximal backward compatibility for those browsers and hence all this ugly browser prefix clutter (google for David Walsh's great post on flip cards). Secondly, I wanted older browsers to at least show the right content and so the invisible (back) face had to be `display: none` while the visible face had to be `display: block-inline` to avoid collapsed margins with content above and below the card. Thirdly, the shifting of the content following the flip card can be achieved by controlling the cards `min-height` property while leaving it's `height: auto` ([credit](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/)). Running the shift a bit ahead of the rotation makes it really smooth.

Finally, the Javascript:

```
function flipCard() {
    var card = $('.flipcard');
    var front = $('.flipcard-front');
    var back = $('.flipcard-back');
    var tallerHight = Math.max(front.height(), back.height()) + 'px';
    // visible/invisible *before* the card is flipped ;D
    var visible = front.hasClass('ms-front-flipped') ? back : front;
    var invisible = front.hasClass('ms-front-flipped') ? front : back;
    var hasTransitioned = false;
    var onTransitionEnded = function () {
        hasTransitioned = true;
        card.css({
            'min-height': '0px'
        });
        visible.css({
            display: 'none',
        });
        // setting focus is important for keyboard users who might otherwise
        // interact with the back of the card once it is flipped.
        invisible.css({
            position: 'relative',
            display: 'inline-block',
        }).find('button:first-child,a:first-child').focus();
    }

    // this is bootstrap support, but you can listen to the browser-specific
    // events directly as well
    card.one($.support.transition.end, onTransitionEnded);

    // for browsers that do not support transitions, like IE9
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!hasTransitioned) {
            onTransitionEnded.apply();
        }
    }, 2000);

    invisible.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'inline-block'
    });

    card.css('min-height', tallerHight);
    // the IE way: flip each face of the card
    front.toggleClass('ms-front-flipped');
    back.toggleClass('ms-back-flipped');
    // the webkit/FF way: flip the card
    card.toggleClass('card-flipped');
}
```

This applies the classes for flipping the card/faces. During the transition, the back face has a `position: absolute` so it is visible while the card is turned. At the same time, the card's height is transitioned. At the end of the transition, the visible face returns to is `position: relative` and the card's height is derestricted leaving back a responsive page.

Hope this helps - sorry for this lengthy post, it's my first :)